# How to find a node quick in Neo4J 3.3.9 - cypher query optimization

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Neo4J [DB model](https://github.com/noduslabs/graphdbmodel):

[image]

I need to be able to find a node of the type `Concept` called "idea" made by the user `infranodus` and see which nodes of the type `Context` it is connected to.

I use the following query, but it's taking too long and doesn't even load...

```
MATCH (ctx:Context)-[:BY]->(u:User{name:'infranodus'}) 
WITH DISTINCT ctx 
MATCH (c:Concept{name:'idea'})-[:AT]->(ctx)<-[:AT]-(cn:Concept) 
RETURN DISINCT c, ctx, count(cn);
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you run an EXPLAIN of the query and attach the expanded query plan to your question?

Comment: Neo4j 3.3.9 is not maintained anymore, only Neo4j 3.5+ versions are supported. You should upgrade ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

adding indexes to the neo4j database would be helpful ( i didnt see any there )  then start your match with the indexed node and traverse from there.    i think that having a

```
MATCH (c:Concept{name:'idea'})-[:AT]->(ctx)<-[:AT]-(cn:Concept)
WHERE (ctx)-[:BY]->(u:User{name:'infranodus'})
```

....
would also avoid querying twice.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index on the name property of nodes with the User label - a unique index would be great for this.
An index for the name property on concept would be good, too (probably without uniqueness constraint - even though you're looking for distinct nodes explicitly).

Start your query from there.

```
MATCH (u:User {name:'infranodus'})
MATCH (c:Concept {name: 'idea'})
MATCH (u)<-[:BY]-(ctx:Context)<-[:AT]-(c)
MATCH (c:Concept{name:'idea'})-[:AT]->(ctx)<-[:AT]-(cn:Concept) 
RETURN c, ctx, size((c)-[:AT]->(ctx)<-[:AT]-(:Concept))
```

Doesn't look as nice, but you're asking for query tuning. Make sure to `PROFILE` your existing query and this. Plus, you had a typo in your query after your return keyword.

Comment: I do have indexes but even the query above is too slow. Hence, I can't run `PROFILE` on them even...